# Extended travel with family members of mixed citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, us-citizens, canadian-citizens, consulates

Background:
My wife is Canadian, my kids and I are US Citizens. We've traveled a bit internationally (mostly to Canada and the occasional Caribbean trip). We are planning years of extended travel in 2018. Starting with Canada, Mexico and then Central America, ending in Panama and then onto the Galapagos and various other places. All members have passports and major US ties (rental property). Wife has a 10-year green card with 4 years left.

Question:
What are the advantages / disadvantages of us starting our travels without her US citizenship? Does it really matter? She intends to become a US citizen at some point, but it hasn't been a priority in the last 11 years. It would be nice if she could vote. It would be nice to NOT have the green card expiry hanging over us.

Some of the things we're planning on doing are considered high physical risk to some - though fairly normal to us. Aside from a major international crisis, what are the reasons we may want to do this or not prior to leaving? Situations you can imagine this being an issue especially in countries mentioned? Here's a situation: What if all of our travel documents were stolen? Would we all end up at a different consulate than her? Or, say we were accused of doing something illegal in one of those countries. Just playing the what-if game here.

Additional Details:
Travel will likely be for 2-3 years with at least 1 visit to the US and 1 to Canada per year, but likely more frequent to see family. First marriage (for both of us), yes kids are US Citizens and do NOT yet have duel citizenship.

Comment: Bottom line if your need help from an embassy, you will end up dealing with two embassies.  Is that reason enough for her to finalize the process to become a citizen, only you can decide.  With 40+ years of extensive travel all over the globe, I have yet (knock on wood) to call upon my embassy for aid, only for routine paperwork.  But that is just my experience, not a guarantee.

Comment: The kids are also Canadians, aren't they?

Comment: Does your wife plan to return to the US at least once a year during the travel period?

Comment: @phoog - the way the OP writes "me & my kids" makes it sound like a second marriage to me.

Comment: "What if all of our travel documents were stolen? Would we all end up at a different consulate than her?" Well, the US embassy isn't going to be able to get Canadian travel documents replaced, right?

Comment: When you say *years*, is it more than 4? Meaning are you expecting the green card to expire before you return?

Comment: All great questions / points! Added details to original question.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's something we hadn't thought of yet. I don't know what the requirements are for her to be in the US in order to NOT lose her permanent residency.

Comment: @Itai the expiration of a US permanent resident card does not imply the loss of permanent resident status (similar to the expiration of a passport not implying loss of citizenship).

Comment: @phoog - It does not but it makes it harder to get in. One of my friend got one replaced at the embassy before going back to the US but it delayed here by almost an entire week.

Comment: From what I remember going from 5 year to 10 year card for her, travel wasn't an issue while waiting for the new card. We just had to schedule the bio-metrics (I'm guessing can only be done at an embassy if not in the US), send in application with proof of what-nots, then wait for the new card in the mail.

Comment: The only thing "Opinion Based" about the question is the unfounded opinion that should it be put on hold. This makes no sense... there is a right / wrong answer to a straightforward question. No "opinions" needed, only facts.

Comment: @maplemale Your question is, basically, "Would it be better for us to all be citizens of the same country?" That's a matter of opinion, as is "What situations do you imagine could become an issue?" You do try to mitigate this by asking for concrete reasons but, overall, I find your question to be very broad and a request for lists of points, which are [felt to be unsuited to Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). I'm not convinced that "primarily opinion based" is the right close reason, but I don't think the question is well-suited to the site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can certainly reword to make more suitable. However, your statement that a "list of points" are unsuited to stack exchange seems to indicate that would be a waste of time and the question in any wording is in appropriate. Please supply supporting documentation of how a question requesting a list of points is unsuited to stack exchange.

Comment: @maplemale I linked to supporting documentation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you need to re-read the documentation you linked. Certainly, the reason for closing the question is incorrect regardless. Asking for a pros and cons list, is not always unsuitable for SE. The Q&A, the documentation you linked and multiple questions on meta support my position. If you disagree, you should take it to stack meta and request a reopen in the mean time.

Comment: I'd like to further add, that the concise answer is further proof that overall this question is concise, constructive and easily answered by experience and documentation. While the question could be reworded and made better certainly, I as a user have little incentive to do so at this point. Unless further clarification is provided as to why it was closed, I am moving on and leaving it as such. Thanks all, for comments and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a possible situation that you may have a problem having two different passports, both from major first-world countries. You'll be OK.

> What if all of our travel documents were stolen? Would we all end up at a different consulate than her?

If your documents are stolen, you both go to police, get a copy of your police report, and go to American consulate first, then to Canadian consulate. At both places, you apply for temporary documents to return home. You don't have to be separated from each other.

> Or, say we were accused of doing something illegal in one of those countries.

There is no benefit or disadvantage from being of the same nationality when you are accused of a crime.

You problems may arise if you are from a first-world country and your companion is from a third-world country. You may be admitted to enter the country, while she may be denied entry. So you'll need to be separated, because you are already inside the country but she'll be put on the return flight.

Comment: The wife may have trouble maintaining her permanent resident status if she's out of the US for "years."

Comment: @phoog That's a good point... Do you know what the requirement for keeping her permanent residency status is?

Comment: @maplemale I can't add an answer because the question is closed, but I've voted to reopen it.  It might be more appropriate on [Expatriates.SE], but in a nutshell, see [Maintaining Permanent Residence](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/maintaining-permanent-residence) and [International Travel as a Permanent Resident](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident).  She may need a re-entry permit or returning resident visa.  There are other considerations, too, including the residence requirement for naturalization.